# Implement the recursion in pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a recursion:

```
C(n) = min{
  C(n/3) + 1 if n ⋮ 3,
  C(n/2) + 1 if n ⋮ 2,
  C(n-1) + 1
}
```

base case being

```
C(n) = 0 for n <= 1
```

How can I implement this recursion in a pythonic way?
This is an attempt to solve the given problem which I was able to solve successfully but I feel the need to implement a recursive solution also.

```
Problem 1: Primitive Calculator
You are given a primitive calculator that can perform the following three operations with the current number x: multiply x by 2, multiply x by 3, or add 1 to x. Your goal is given a positive integer n, find the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.

Problem Description

Task. Given an integer n, compute the minimum number of operations needed to obtain the number n starting from the number 1.

Output Format. In the first line, output the minimum number k of operations needed to get n from 1. In the second line output a sequence of intermediate numbers. That is, the second line should contain positive integers a0, a2,…, a(k-1) such that a0 =1, a(k-1) =n and for all 0≤i<k-1, ai+1 is equal to either ai + 1, 2 x ai, or 3 x ai. If there are many such sequences, output any one of them.

Sample 1.

Input: 5

Output:

3

1 2 4 5

Explanation:
Here, we first multiply 1 by 2 two times and then add 1 ( ((1 x 2) x 2) + 1). Another possibility is to first multiply by 3 and then add 1 two times. Hence “1 3 4 5” is also a valid output in this case.

Sample 2:

Input: 96234

Output:

14

1 3 9 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234

Explanation:
Again, another valid output in this case is “1 3 9 10 11 33 99 297 891 2673 8019 16038 16039 48117 96234”.

Your goal is to design and implement a dynamic programming solution for this problem. A natural subproblem in this case is the following: C(n) is the minimum number of operations required to obtain n from 1 (using the three primitive operations). How to express C(n) through C(n/3), C(n/2), C(n-1)?
```

Comment: I don't recognize the `⋮` notation.  Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: n ⋮ 3 means if n%3 == 0

Comment: How is the `min` to be interpreted with those conditional elements? If it's divisible by 3 (but not by 2), then return the minimum of C(n/3) + 1 and C(n-1) + 1?

Comment: Which problem are you having writing this code yourself? It seems like most of this should be fairly trivial to convert to Python code (if you understand Python, that is - if you don't, you can find plenty of tutorials and code samples online to help with that). If you don't know what a specific part of this should look like, asking about that will probably lead to a question that's more useful for others and where you'll get answers that focus more on explaining the parts you don't understand (instead of just getting "here is the code" answers).

Comment: What I tried was take a global variable for storing the total count and local variables for storing results from potential solutions which always resluted in final answer being zero. I wasn't able to figure out the reason.
I understand that my question should have been more specific

Answer (score 3):

```
def C(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0

    m= C(n-1)
    if n % 3 == 0:
        m= min(m, C(n/3))
    if n % 2 == 0:
        m= min(m, C(n/2))
    return m + 1
```

It might be worth to consider memoization.

```
Cache= {}

def C(n):
    global Cache

    if n <= 1:
        return 0

    try:
        return Cache[n]

    except:
        m= C(n-1)
        if n % 3 == 0:
            m= min(m, C(n/3))
        if n % 2 == 0:
            m= min(m, C(n/2))
        m+= 1
        Cache[n]= m
        return m
```

I am unsure whether it is better to test for `n <= 1` first.

Comment: Thank you. I did use memoization, but was having trouble with the recursive one.